# How to compute generators in biquadratic extension

Tags: number-theory, extension-field, prime-factorization

I'm working in this setting: $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$, and let $K_1= \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}],K_2= \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}],K_3= \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{6}]$ the three subfields. I know that $2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is totally ramified in each of the $K_i$ ($2$ divides $2,6$ and $3 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$) and I know how to compute generators of $2$ in each of the $K_i$. Moreover, I know that $2$ is totally ramified in $K$ namely, $2R=Q^4$ where $R$ is the number ring of $K$ and $Q$ is the only prime of $R$ lying over $2$.

I want to compute $Q$ finding its generators. I did it using SageMath, but I want to achieve the result without software. Can you help me? (I have no idea about the starting point)

I'm using Marcus'book "Number fields" if you want a reference.

Comment: If you can express $K$ as a simple extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, then you can apply Dedekind's theorem as described [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf). Your case is a bit subtle because it can be hard to choose an $\alpha$ such that $2 \nmid [\mathcal{O}_K : \mathbb{Z}[a]]$. I cheated and using a computer found $\alpha$ with minimal polynomial $T^4 - 4 T^3 - 46 T^2 - 20 T - 2$ such that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Then $2 \mathcal{O}_K = (2, \alpha)^4$ by Theorem 8 of the notes. In fact $Q$ is even principal, but again I don't see how to show this by hand.

Comment: That was my issue! I was trying this way but without success because of the problems of finding such $\alpha$. Of course I tryed with $\alpha=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. However, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The $\Bbb{Q}$-minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}-1$ is $(x+1)^2-3=x^2+2x-2$

The $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$-minimal polynomial of $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is $x^2+\sqrt{2}x-1$

The $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$-minimal polynomial of $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}+1$ is $$(x-1)^2+\sqrt{2}(x-1)-1= x^2+(\sqrt{2}-2)x-\sqrt{2}$$

> This polynomial is Eisenstein at $\sqrt{2}O_{\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}$ so $K/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is totally ramified of degree $2$ and its uniformizer is $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}+1$ ie. $$\sqrt{2}O_K=(\sqrt{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}+1)^2$$

Thus $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is totally ramified of degree $4$ and its uniformizer is  $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}+1$

ie. $$2O_K=(2,\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}+1)^4$$

The same algorithm works for arbitrary totally ramified extensions.

Comment: I didn’t know this method, hence I have some questions:

Comment: 1) why you take exactly those polynomials?

Comment: 2)What is the uniformizer?

Comment: Do you know extensions of the p-adic numbers ? $\sqrt{3}$ generates the extension thus if $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{2})$ is totally ramified then there is some $u,v\in \Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{2})$ such that $u \sqrt{3}-v$ is an uniformizer ie. its minimal polynomial is Eisenstein (an uniformizer is an element of valuation $v(\sqrt{2})/2$)

Comment: You can replace $\Bbb{Q}_2$ by the local ring $(\Bbb{Z}-(2))^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ it works more or less the same way. An uniformizer of a DVR generates its unique maximal ideal.

Comment: Thank for clarification but I have not studied p-adic numbers yet, so this is pretty tricky for me to understand. If you know other ways to achieve the same result, please tell me.

Comment: I told you, you need to sit in the DVR $R=(\Bbb{Z}-(2))^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ and the totally ramified (ie. same residue fields) tower $R[\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}+1]/R[\sqrt{2}]/R$ whose unique maximal ideals are $(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}}+1),(\sqrt{2}),(2)$.

Comment: And the need to study finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ is the point, they are made exactly to answer those kind of questions